# 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `checkLoginStatus()` like this. It will be return `true` or `false`

```
checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(sharedPreferences.getString("token"));
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("token") != null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And I have a `button A` with the code below

```
press: () => {
if(checkLoginStatus()) {
      //..Some code
     } else {
      //..
     }
   }
```

I tap on `button A` and got

`Another exception was thrown: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'`

Why ? And how can I check `checkLoginStatus()` return `true` or `false` in `if()` condition ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add **return** type to `checkLoginStatus` like

```dart
Future<bool> checkLoginStatus() async {
  //
}
```

- Await for future to complete in if statement

```dart
() async => {
if(await checkLoginStatus()) {
  //
}
```

**OR**

Cast to `Future<bool>`

```dart
() async => {
if(await (checkLoginStatus() as Future<bool>)) {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `await` for `checkLoginStatus()` as Currently it has type of `Future<dynamic>`.

```dart
press: () => async {
final _checkLoginStatus = await checkLoginStatus();
if(_checkLoginStatus) {
      //..Some code
     } else {
      //..
     }
   }
```

Also, Do give a return type to your method.

```dart
Future<bool> checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(sharedPreferences.getString("token"));
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("token") != null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```